# Let $R=\frac{X}{Y}$. Determine $\mathbb{P}(R>1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Let $X,Y$ be random independent variables, each with geometric distribution.

$$\begin{align*}&f_{X}(x)=\alpha\beta^{x-1};\quad x\geqslant1,\alpha+\beta=1,0<\alpha<1,\\&f_{Y}(y)=pq^{y-1};\quad y\geqslant1,p+q=1,0<p<1.\end{align*}$$

Let $R=\frac{X}{Y}$. Determine $\mathbb{P}(R>1)$.

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X>Y)&=1-\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant Y)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(X<Y)-\mathbb{P}(X=Y).\end{align*}$$

Since $\mathbb{P}(Y<X)=\mathbb{P}(X<Y)$,

$$\mathbb{P}(X<Y)=\frac{1-\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X}{Y}=1\right)}{2}=\frac{1-\sum_{x=0}^{r}\mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}\left(Y=\frac{x}{r}\right)}{2}.$$

The answer should be $\frac{p\beta}{1-q\beta}$, but my equation doesn't yield that. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a number of mistakes in your assumptions, for example where did you get $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)$?

But you are on the right track that $P(R>1)$ is the same as $P(X>Y)$. Then you only need to know geometric series relations to solve it.

$$
\begin{align}
P(X>Y)
&=
\sum_{y=1}^\infty p(Y=y) p(X>y)
\\
&=
\sum pq^{y-1} (\alpha\beta^{y}+\alpha\beta^{y+1}+...)
\\
&=p\alpha\beta\sum (q\beta)^{y-1}{1\over 1 - \beta}
\\
&={p\beta\over 1-q\beta}
\end{align}
$$
where I have used $\alpha=1-\beta$ and the usual summation of a geometric series relation twice.